# Selecting executors in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, executors

In my company we're using a single Jenkins build server. We have resource-heavy interdependent build jobs as well as smaller ones, equally important. During peak times, the big builds tend to block the pipeline.

My question: is it somehow possible to select a single executor (not a node) and assign certain jobs to it so it will always be free for the lightweight ones?

I *know* I could set up slave nodes, even on the same machine, and that it's very common and much supported by Jenkins. Our server could handle a vm running as a slave, but before I go to the trouble I want to know if there's a shorter way.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned setting up a slave node is the right way to go.

That said if you're limited on resources you could perhaps run the slave client on the same server as which you are running Jenkins?

The comments on this ticket suggest that this should work:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4850

Comment: Wonderful! In all the information I found, it always seemed that people had either physical nodes or VMs. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I've not done what you're trying but I have setup many slaves before and I can't see why this wouldn't work. (The only thing niggling in the back of my head are port numbers but I believe those are configurable)

Answer (score 0):

In a setup where there is no Jenkins master-slave configuration, you *do* have settings to restrict # of executors. Just go to `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System`

On this page, you will find the option `# of executors`

There is a plugin as well which might be of use if the above suggestion doesn't meet your requirement: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

Comment: Yes, we used that option to increase the throughput during peak times by just increasing the number of executors.^^ But that didn't really solve the problem because if the lightweight jobs were a little further down the pipeline, the "new" executors were simply taken up by the heavy ones as well.